# how to run android project on phone?

Tags: android

How do we run out android project on a phone? If we use Eclipse, we will set emulator to run it, but how about if we want to test it in real so we can see the output? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect your device via USB in debugging mode, and you can see it's there when you run adb devices, then running your application from Eclipse should default to the connected (physical) device.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see your phone when you run adb you are probably on windows!

In that case you need to download drivers so that you can test on your phone.

all you need to know and more: http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: May be also under Linux if /etc/udev/rules.d are not configured as described in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html. Any more systems to bash?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse installs it to your device when you run it; you can also install it manually. Once installed, you'll find it in your app icon drawer; you'll have one icon for each activity you configure to be user launchable.